# How could I make an input empty while not making the respective property empty with `[(ngModel)]`?

Tags: angular

How could I make an input empty while not making the respective property empty with `[(ngModel)]` ?

E.g. I have the input:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="foo" />
```

Now in a component I would like to have the `foo` property being non-empty, not null or undefined. But I would like to have nothing in view. How could I achieve this.

The best solution I was come up with so far is to add another `input` and show it instead of mine one as it will be necessary. But the maintenance of such a solution is not very straightforward. So, I hope to find a better solution.

Here is what I mean by my current solution:

```
<input *ngIf="!inputShouldBeEmpty" [(ngModel)]="foo" />
<input *ngIf="inputShouldBeEmpty" />
```

I need this for the following scenario:

I have an input. It needs the `[(ngModel)]` feature. But at some point I would like nothing to be displayed in the input (just a styling requirement), while having the property value not being emptied.

Comment: "at some point" what does it mean ? if you bind 'ngModel' with a variable, it will always display its value.

Comment: @micronyks, that is the case. I have a scenario when nothing should be displayed in the input, but I need the value to remain and not being lost.

Comment: As @micronyks suggested, ngModel is a 2 way binding technique and will always display the value bound to the variable "foo"